# Regex Constructor doesn't work for matching a variable in a string word

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

I am trying to find number of occurrences of a string letter(variable) in a string word, using a regex constructor but it doesn't work.

```
function getNumberOfOccurrences()
{
    //get input from user:
    var inputWord = document.getElementById("wordInputField").value;
    inputWord = inputWord+""; // turn it into a string
    var inputLetter = document.getElementById("letterInputField").value;
    inputLetter = inputLetter+""; // turn it into a string

    if(checkInput(inputWord , inputLetter)) // other function that checks the input
    {
        var rgxInputLetter = new RegExp(inputLetter, "g"); //use regex constructor for the match function:

        var resultArray = inputWord.match(rgxInputLetter); // use match to find occurrences. match returns an array

        var occurences = resultArray.length; // length of array should be the occurrences

        if(isNaN(occurences) && occurences >= 0) // check that match function worked and an array was returned
        {
            document.getElementById("resultField").innerHTML = "There are "+occurences + " occurrences of: \""+inputLetter+"\" in the word: \""+inputWord+"\"";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("resultField").innerHTML = "There are no occurrences of: \""+inputLetter+"\" in the word: \""+inputWord+"\"";
        }



    }


}
```

It always gives me an **error** that the **resultArray** is **null**.
even if I write **inputLetter = "a"** or **inputWord = "something"** just before the match function.
**Why it doesn't work?**

Comment: Have you tried this: http://regexr.com/ ?

Comment: How many `a` are in `something`?

Comment: thanks for that. it's a cool website.

Answer (score 0):

Found that it actually works , and the problem was the last if condition **isNaN(occurences)**.
The condition as it is checks that occurences is **not** a number.
Should have added a ! sign. -_-
so this fixed it:
`if( ! isNaN(occurences) && occurences >= 0)`